# A runtime warning if QOpenGLWidget is added via Qt Designer

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qopenglwidget

I have added a QOpenGLWidget object on the main window and this makes the console have a lot of messages such as

```
QOpenGLContext::makeCurrent() called with non-opengl surface 0x2623b7b7460
QRhiGles2: Failed to make context current. Expect bad things to happen.
QOpenGLContext::makeCurrent() called with non-opengl surface 0x2623dab3450
QRhiGles2: Failed to make context current. Expect bad things to happen.
QOpenGLContext::makeCurrent() called with non-opengl surface 0x2623b7b7460
QRhiGles2: Failed to make context current. Expect bad things to happen.
```

My .pro file is

```
QT       += core gui openglwidgets

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

CONFIG += c++17

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
    mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
    mainwindow.ui

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

mainwindow.ui is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
    <item>
     <widget class="QOpenGLWidget" name="openGLWidget"/>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>17</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

The mainwindow.h and mainwindow.cpp files are regular, such as QtCreator generated them.

I have tried adding the line QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_ForceRasterWidgets, false); but there are errors both with and without this line:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_ForceRasterWidgets, false);

    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Then I deleted the ui and added the QOpenGLWidget manually:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    QWidget *centralWidget = new QWidget(this);
    this->setCentralWidget( centralWidget );
    QGridLayout * gridLayout = new QGridLayout( centralWidget );

    QOpenGLWidget* ow = new QOpenGLWidget(this);
    gridLayout->addWidget(ow);
}
```

There were no errors in this case, when QOpenGLWidget was added manually. But it is not comfortable to make a form without Qt Designer.

Can you advise how to get out of the errors about QOpenGLContext and QRhiGles2?

My version of Qt is 6.5, VS2019 compiler, Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding a dummy widget:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
: QMainWindow(parent) {
    new QOpenGLWidget(this);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).